# Finding others with H2a1 maternal DNA?

Tags: dna, mitochondrial-dna

I only have distance 3 on FTDNA matches. I am not sure if I understand FTDNA correctly, but the time frame for their identification of the mtDNA is approx 1000 CE.  The majority of the matches are in Finland, with the next frequency in Eastern Europe.   Based on FTDNA information and other articles I have read, distance 3 must be a relationship in the far distant past. My mother was Welsh.  I was interested in finding other h2a1's to see if they had any distance 0-2 matches or any other information.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is different to bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites.  With no question mark in your question body it is difficult to determine what the question is that you wish to ask.  Would you be able to use the [edit] button beneath your question to try and make that clearer, please?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you've got the right idea. mtDNA is passed identically from generation to generation with only an occasional mutation every so often. In your case, going up 1000 years and down again 1000 years, you and the other people have only 3 differences.

What that means is that mtDNA is basically useless for genealogical purposes. The only real use is to determine ancestral origins, and find out the "Eve" you descend from.

It can be used to disprove that your mother's line does not intersect another person's mother's line, if their mtDNA first letter is different, but it really can't be used to prove anything you might be able to use in your genealogical research.

So looking for other h2a1's won't do anything for you. You'd be much better off doing an Autosomal test which will give you matches that are possible to track down.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add to @lkessler answer, that the best choice is to make Autosomal testing for eldest relatives, because the size of matched DNA segments fades with decreasing of relationship degree very fast. So we can surely determine first or second cousins and more distant relatives are lost in the mess of speculative matches. It the reason why the Autosomal test of your parents (or parents of parents) are more useful than your own.